# How to get selected items from listbox has checkboxes in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, listbox

This is the ListBox code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="courseslistview" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding .}" 
         FontSize="18.667" 
         FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" 
         LayoutUpdated="courseslistview_LayoutUpdated">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How can I use C# to get all the checked checkboxes in the above ListBox?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It would probably be best to bind the `CheckBox` to the `IsSelected` property of the `ListBoxItem`, like so:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox Content="{Binding .}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you can get the checked/selected items from the ListBox.SelectedItems collection. You'd also have to set [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) to Multiple.

Comment: Am working on WP app and i get the following error.
The property 'AncestorType' was not found in RelativeSource and 'AncestorType' is not recognized or it not accessible. Can you also give solution for how it comes in Windows Phone?

Comment: @BalasubramaniM - This question is specific to WPF. I'd recommend asking a separate question, if it hasn't already been asked before.

Comment: and how to get checked checkbox value

Comment: The items that are checked would be the in `ListBox.SelectedItems` collection. Any that are not in that collection would not be checked.