# Getting the content of a checkbox within and Items Collection within a ListBox with wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I am pretty new to C#, I've been having this problem for a little while now. I have a ListBox named "listBox" which is bound to an Items Collection which has over 100 checkbox, each with a different content (or checkbox label).

I am trying to loop through each checkbox, and if it is checked, print the content into the console. I am able to detect if something is checked or not, however is definitely NOT the most efficient way of doing it. See my code below:

```
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string checkState = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            checkState = listBox.Items[i].ToString().Substring(listBox.Items[i].ToString().Length - 5, 5);
            if (checkState != "False")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item " + i + " is checked");
            }
        }
    }
```

This code does work for detecting if something is checked or not properly. However it'd be more efficient if I was able to get the actual true/false property from the checkboxes in the ItemsCollection. I have tried numerous ways to attempt to get the checked state, as well as the checkbox content, but sadly I am coming up dry in every attempt. Here are a few of the things I have tried to get the content from one of these checkboxes:

`Console.WriteLine(listBox.Items[i].ToString());`

`Console.WriteLine(listBox.Items.GetItemAt(i).ToString());`

`Console.WriteLine(listBox.Items.GetItemAt(i).Equals(0).ToString());`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525920/how-to-get-selected-items-from-listbox-has-checkboxes-in-wpf

Comment: Thanks for the fast response @CoderForHire. This looks like it can get me the checked state, but not the checkbox content. In addition. I copied the answer from tat question into my listbox, but I am getting a bad markup error. `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding .}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you ideally want is to have a class of data objects in your collection, not a collection of UI objects.

```
public class MyDataObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var items = new ObservableCollection<MyDataObject>();
// TODO: populate collection

listBox.ItemsSource = items;
```

Now when you bind it, `listbox.Items` contains your `ObservableCollection<MyDataObject>`, and you can just check the values from there

```
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(MyDataObject item in listBox.Items)
    {
        if (item.IsChecked)
            Console.WriteLine("Item " + item.Caption + " is checked");
    }
}
```

As a side note, if you don't need selection behavior an [`ItemsControl`](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) might be a better fit for a series of controls than a ListBox. The XAML would probably look something like this :

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="myItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Caption}" Checked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
var items = new ObservableCollection<MyDataObject>();
items.Add(new MyDataObject() { Caption = "A" });
items.Add(new MyDataObject() { Caption = "B" });
items.Add(new MyDataObject() { Caption = "C" });
items.Add(new MyDataObject() { Caption = "D" });
items.Add(new MyDataObject() { Caption = "E" });

myItemsControl.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this in just a bit! It may not be today, so sorry if I can't give you an immediate response!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you you need me to clarify anything :)

Comment: I'm still new to C# and I am running into some issues here! I tried googling around but I am not able to come up with anything that works. It appears to add an item to my ItemCollection, I need to use `Items.Add("foo");` However, I am not sure where to add this code (I apologize again for ignorance to this language). Does this go under the MyDataObject class, or any class?

Comment: I am having one last issue, I have almost figured this out. I am adding items to the items collection in the following way: `CheckBox Itm0 = new CheckBox();
            Itm0.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "Example Text" + "/n", TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow };
            items.Add(Itm0);` The `items.Add(Itm0);` line causes an error, stating that I cannot convert a `Systems.Windows.Controls.Checkboc` to a `MyDataObject`. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: @AlexWeber I added some sample XAML to my answer. You should not be creating UI objects at all for the collection. Just bind the collection to an ItemsControl or ListBox that has the correct template and it will auto-generate your UI items for you.