# Binding SelectedItem to IsChecked

Tags: powershell, data-binding

I have listBox modified for check boxes. I would like to bind the `selectedItem` to the check so that I can use `$WPFlbSiteList.SelectedItem` as the basis of selecting items that are checked.

Basically, I have generated a list I need the checks to equate to the selected item. This selected item also needs to work in a multi selection capacity rather than one at a time.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbSiteList" SelectionMode="MultiExtended" Margin="355,45,411,1014" ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <CheckBox Content="{Binding .}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Margin="2,2,0,0"/>
           </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My function to write to the console which of my checked items are selected.

```
$WPFbtnUpdate.Add_Click({ 

    #List the sites that are ticked
    foreach ($WPFlbSiteList.Items in $WPFlbSiteList){

        $x=$WPFlbSiteList.SelectedItems

        write-host $x
    }
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected items from listbox has checkboxes in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525920/how-to-get-selected-items-from-listbox-has-checkboxes-in-wpf)

Comment: Hi Mathias, that mostly worked I just need to be able to select more than one at a time I changed out the selection mode for multi selection but I am now getting an error attempting to display the form.

Comment: Without knowing the error it's a bit hard to help you, but for one I don't think `MultiExtended` is a valid SelectionMode, should be "Extended" or "Multiple"

Comment: Great that worked! I wasn't aware of the SelectionMode values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments you can bind the checkbox `IsChecked` value to `IsSelected` of it's relative ancestor (the listbox) with:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected" />
```

Your real issue, however, seems to be that you're using an invalid value for the ListBox' [`SelectionMode` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

In WPF, the [valid selection modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) are:

> ```
> Extended   - The user can select multiple consecutive items while holding down the SHIFT key.
> Multiple   - The user can select multiple items without holding down a modifier key.
> Single     - The user can select only one item at a time.
> ```